# How to send a UIView element backwards in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview

So I have a Button which i have added in main.Storyboard, along with a main background for the View, and then in the viewController.swift file, I have created a UIView rectangle shape which I want to sit behind that button (as a background for it).

The problem is, when I added the rectangle UIView it always added it in front of the button. So I researched online and found the sendSubviewToBack code. I have added this in, but it sends it all the way behind the main UIImage background of the view.

Is there a way i can just send this UIView behind the button but in front of the UIImage background?

```
func nextBarDisplayed() {

    let theHeight = self.view.frame.height
    nextBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 7/255, green: 152/255, blue: 253/255, alpha: 0.5)
    nextBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: theHeight - 50, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50)
    self.view.insertSubview(nextBar, aboveSubview: myBackgroundView)

}
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

From [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html):

```
bringSubviewToFront(_:)
sendSubviewToBack(_:)
removeFromSuperview()
insertSubview(_:atIndex:)
insertSubview(_:aboveSubview:)
insertSubview(_:belowSubview:)
exchangeSubviewAtIndex(_:withSubviewAtIndex:)
```

You can bring your bar to the front using:

```
view.bringSubviewToFront(nextBar)
```

Your send your view to the back of the bar using:

```
nextBar.view.sendSubviewToBack(myView)
```

Comment: Great news! Please don't forget to leave the wrong and the correct way to people can understand what the problem. Good luck finishing your app!

Answer (score 9):

For Swift 4:

```
self.view.sendSubviewToBack(toBack: myView)
```

Comment: And Swift 4.2, been renamed back to `sendSubviewToBack`

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4.2 it can be done with:

```
self.sendSubviewToBack(view: viewSentToBack)
```

An object in the view that is linked by an IBOutlet can be sent to back using the above function.