# How can I animate a UIView underneath the UINavigationController's view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

Right now I'm animating a little banner that sometimes appears directly under the NavigationBar. This UIView lives on a subclass of UINavigationController in my app.

I want to animate the banner view up and under the navigationBar when its time for the view to disappear (as opposed to animating it's height to 0 which can cause wacky things to occur to subviews of the banner). However, it's always animating on top of the navBar.

I've tried sending my view to the back (-sendSubviewToBack:) however, then I don't see it all. Then I tried -bringSubviewToFront, and giving it the navigationBar's view. That didn't work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to need to be a bit more deliberate with your hierarchy (it's going back too far). Here's a good answer on how to be more specific with your placement. [How to send a UIView element backwards in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769052/how-to-send-a-uiview-element-backwards-in-swift)

Specifically, you want to use

```
insertSubview(_:belowSubview:)
```

and place your view directly beneath the nav bar view that should hide it.

Just a tip, you can bring up the UI debug for some added help.

Comment: Got it. I used -bringSubviewToFront: to bring forward the navigationBar.