# Swift: Adding the subview prevents user from using the app. Lottie Animations

Tags: ios, swift

I've been messing around with Lottie animations. I've tried to implement a brief animation that would be triggered on a button click. My code basically does its thing but the problem is it does it only once. Then the buttons become unclickable, just as if something was on top of the view that user interacts with (at least this is my presumption. How can I keep using the Lotti animation and make it go back to the main view of the app where the button is clickable again after the animation?

Here is the code snippet that I'm working with:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    
    lazy var backgroundAnimationView: AnimationView = {
    
    
    
        let animationView = AnimationView()
        
        view.addSubview(animationView)
        animationView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        animationView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        animationView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        animationView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        animationView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
    view.addSubview(animationView)
        return animationView
        
        
        
    }()
    
    
    private func playBackgroundAnimation(){
        let animation = Animation.named("confettiBurst")
        backgroundAnimationView.animation = animation
        backgroundAnimationView.play(fromProgress: 0, toProgress: 1, loopMode: .playOnce)
            }


 @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!


 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
       // createLayer()
    
        //    who .  what    =  value
      
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        
        
    }


@IBAction func rollButtonPress(_ sender: UIButton) {
        playBackgroundAnimation()
        
        button.alpha = 1
        
        
        print("button tapped")
    }

}
```

Comment: You are adding the animation view twice and you are adding it over the top of your `view`, so you are correct; there is something on top of the buttons; your animation view.  You could hide the animation view after it is done and then unhide it when you want to run the animation again or you could remove it and add a new animation view each time.

Comment: Hello again. I've removed the doubled animation view call. I've tried following other stackoverflow questions, for example this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769052/how-to-send-a-uiview-element-backwards-in-swift but after hours of trying im still unable to hide and unhide the animation. It either isn't visible at all and app works or the animation is visible but buttons become unclickable. Could you maybe expand on your idea of hiding the animation with some short code example?  If you have some spare time for me of course, I would be very thankful!

Comment: My first thought was to add "animationView.removeFromSuperview()" somewhere but the animationView isn't in the scope anywhere else than the Lazy Var. So the only place where I can hide the animation is in the Lazy var, which doesn't work :/

Comment: Okay, sorry for spamming. I've fixed the problem and will elaborate on it in a separate comment under this post. Nonetheless thank you very much for helping me getting on the right track! Wouldn't have made it this far without your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the thinking and with help of Paulw11 I've managed to fix the problem. I will leave the answer below for anyone who encounters the same annoyance in the future.

```
    private func playBackgroundAnimation(){
        let animation = Animation.named("confettiBurst")
        backgroundAnimationView.animation = animation
        
        backgroundAnimationView.play{_ in 
            self.backgroundAnimationView.isHidden = false
            
        }
        
        backgroundAnimationView.play(fromProgress: 0, toProgress: 1, loopMode: .playOnce)
    
        backgroundAnimationView.play { (finished) in
            self.backgroundAnimationView.isHidden = true
        }
        
    }
```

I've simply added some code that unhides the animationView on the beginning of the call and hides it after. It worked like a charm. Now the animation goes off and still lets user tap all the buttons in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I now use [PKHUD](https://github.com/pkluz/PKHUD) to achieve this function. Originally used `MBProgressHUD`, but it has not been maintained for many years. The following `UIView extension` is for the convenience of syntax.

```
extension UIView {
    
    // MARK: -
    func showHud(message: String) {
        HUD.dimsBackground = false
        
        let onView = self
        
        if (message.isEmpty == false) {
            HUD.show(.labeledProgress(title: message, subtitle: nil), onView: onView)
        } else {
            HUD.show(.progress, onView: onView)
        }
    }
    
    func hideHud() {
        HUD.hide()
    }
    
    /// Only text message
    func showTextHud(_ text: String) {
        /*
         Reference url: https://github.com/pkluz/PKHUD
         */
        HUD.show(.label(text), onView: self)
    }
}

// Example:

// 
@IBAction func OnBtnNext(_ sender: Any) {
     // block UI with animation
     self.view.showHud(message: "")

     // call web api do something, and wait result 
     webApi.doSomething() { [weak self] (isDone: Bool) in
         // un-block UI
         self?.view.hideHud()
     }
}
```